# ElectronJS & React DevTools: "Extension server error: Operation failed: http://localhost:3000/ has no execution context", source: devtools://

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, parceljs

My React + Electron.js app is using 2 DevTools extensions (React Developer Tools & Redux DevTools) installed using the `electron-devtools-installer` package when the app is started in a development environment. Parcel 1.X is used to bundle the app and to provide hot reloading.

On the first run using `yarn start`, no errors occur, with the following output seen on running the app:

```
(node:60573) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 bundled listeners added to [Bundler]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
[0] (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[0] ✨  Built in 6.67s.
[1] (electron) The default value of app.allowRendererProcessReuse is deprecated, it is currently "false".  It will change to be "true" in Electron 9.  For more information please check https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397
[1] Added Extension:  React Developer Tools
[1] Added Extension:  Redux DevTools
```

If we go to the `Components` tab in Chrome DevTools, we see React Developer Tools working as expected.

[image]

However, after the app hot-reloads on detecting a code change, we start to see the errors:

```
[1] [60597:0519/005808.141307:ERROR:CONSOLE(131)] "Extension server error: Operation failed: http://localhost:3000/ has no execution context", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/extensions/ExtensionServer.js (131)
[1] [60597:0519/005808.142973:ERROR:CONSOLE(131)] "Extension server error: Operation failed: http://localhost:3000/ has no execution context", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/extensions/ExtensionServer.js (131)
[1] [60597:0519/005808.143059:ERROR:CONSOLE(131)] "Extension server error: Operation failed: http://localhost:3000/ has no execution context", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/extensions/ExtensionServer.js (131)
[1] [60597:0519/005808.146899:ERROR:CONSOLE(40)] "[object Object]", source: chrome-extension://react-developer-tools/build/main.js (40)
```

If we go to the `Components` tab in Chrome DevTools, we now observe an empty screen.

[image]

**Question:** What might be causing the error here?

---

- electron@8.3.0
- electron-devtools-installer@3.0.0
- react@16.13.1
- redux@4.0.5
- parcel-bundler@1.12.4
- Node v14.2.0
- Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.3

**electron.js**

```
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;

const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");


let mainWindow;

const installExtensions = async () => {
  const { default: installExtension, REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS, REDUX_DEVTOOLS } = require('electron-devtools-installer');

  const extensions = [REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS, REDUX_DEVTOOLS];
  for (const extension of extensions) {
    try {
      const name = await installExtension(extension);
      console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('An error occurred: ', err);
    }
  }
}

function createWindow() {
  const { width, height } = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: Math.round(width),
    height: Math.round(heigh),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      preload: __dirname + '/preload.js'
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
  );
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => (mainWindow = null));
}

app.on("ready", async () => {
  createWindow();

  if (isDev) {
    // Install extensions
    await installExtensions();

    // Auto-open dev tools
    mainWindow.webContents.on("did-frame-finish-load", () => {
      mainWindow.webContents.once("devtools-opened", () => {
        mainWindow.focus();
      });
      mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools({
        mode: 'undocked'
      });
    });
  }
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

if any one getting the same problem and there is another issue like when you run the app for the first time it's showing a blank screen without the page just with main component to fix that just Change your `BrowserRouter` with a `HashRouter`. and i got this both problems but after changing this it's fixed

Comment: Awesome, this worked very well for me, thank you sir :)

Answer (score 2):

I had to deal with the same issue and I couldn't find a way for a long time.

What solved for me the issue, I added a callback function for `did-frame-finish-load`. So in my case it looks like this:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  const mainWindow = createMainWindow(__dirname);

  mainWindow.webContents.on("did-frame-finish-load", async () => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      await installExtensions();
    }
  });
  // Receiver(ipcMain) Module
  receiver();

  // Updater Module
  updater(mainWindow);
});
```

**installExetensions.js**

```
async function installExtensions() {
  const installer = require('electron-devtools-installer');
  const forceDownload = !!process.env.UPGRADE_EXTENSIONS;
  const extensions = ['REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS', 'REDUX_DEVTOOLS'];

  return Promise.all(
    extensions.map(name => installer.default(installer[name], forceDownload))
  ).catch(err => console.log(err));
}

export { installExtensions };
```

I think this solution can work in your scenario as well.